# how can i set this button to appear with the transition

Tags: html, css, z-index

in my present code, button initially is visible and with the transition, it becomes hidden behind the box. What i want is "my button initially should be hidden and should appear with the transition". Thanks in advance..
P.S. No jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <div id="anim">

    </div>
    <input type="button" value="this should be behind" id="btn" />

</body>
</html>

<style>

#anim{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transition: all 2s; 
   -moz-transition: all 2s; 
    -ms-transition: all 2s; 
     -o-transition: all 2s; 
        transition: all 2s;
}

#anim:hover{
height:400px
}

#btn{
z-index: -1;
position:fixed;
margin-top: 300px;

}

</style>
```

Comment: This sentence in completely ununderstable: "I want that my button appears as the width of the left end of red box increases." Please elaborate to get better answers.

Comment: sorry what you actually want?

Comment: sorry, if it was not clear... i edited the question and also my code, so please have a look.

Comment: it is still not clear. your question says "*it should appear..*", but your button text says "*this should be behind*" ? what do you really want?

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9BSkJ/1/ ?

Comment: @abhitalks  very close... but i want it with opacity one.

Comment: @ABCoder: "*..with opacity one*"?? I don't get it.

Comment: @abhitalks please look at this "http://jsfiddle.net/7L9va/"  here the button appears before the red bottom end of box reaches it, i dont want this

Comment: @ABCoder: just increase the delay: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9BSkJ/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `opacity` of the button on hover without changing the structure of your document using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Here's how:

```
#anim:hover + #btn
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Edit:** You can also delay this using `transition-delay` on the button:

```
#btn
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 700ms;
    z-index: 2;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

Below is the complete CSS, as some changes were also made to initially hide the button, and to properly set the `z-index` property.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7L9va/).

```
#anim{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transition: all 2s; 
   -moz-transition: all 2s; 
    -ms-transition: all 2s; 
     -o-transition: all 2s; 
        transition: all 2s;
}

#anim:hover{
height:400px
}

#anim:hover + #btn{
    opacity: 1;
}

#btn{
opacity: 0;
transition-delay: 700ms;
z-index: 2;
position:fixed;
margin-top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: here the button appears before the bottom end of red box reaches it.I want it to appear as the bottom end of red box reaches it

Comment: @ABCoder I've updated my answer above. Please upvote any answers that were helpful, and if we solved your problem consider accepting an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/175166

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
#anim{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
   -webkit-transition: width 2s ease; 
   -moz-transition: width 2s ease; 
    -ms-transition: width 2s ease; 
     -o-transition: width 2s ease; 
        transition: width 2s ease;
}

#anim:hover{
     width: 600px;
}

#btn{
   margin-left: 100px;
   margin-top: 100px;
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear; 
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear; 
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s linear; 
     -o-transition: opacity 2s linear; 
        transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
#anim:hover #btn{
    opacity:1;
}
```

and add your button inside `#anim` div, just like this:

```
<div id="anim">
    <input type="button" value="this should be behind" id="btn" />
</div>
```

and all this without javascript, only css.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/piserozi/1/edit)

Comment: no..no.. this is not what i want. in this case you are changing the opacity. i want that according to your code, as the right end of red box moves, the button comes in picture with its opacity one. The button is in the region where transition take place.

Comment: Okay, so what's the initial position you want for the button before transition starts and do you want it hided or not before that?

Comment: let the left margin be '350px' in your code and i want the button to be hidden initially

Comment: and its final position?